# Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition uninstall stuck on Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Objects (x64)

Tags: uninstallation, visual-studio-2015

I am having the most nightmarish time trying to get VS2015 Community Edition on my Windows 10 machine. After the installation was hanging for two days I ended up killing it and rebooting. I now have a "Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 with Updates" entry in "Programs and Features" and I don't seem to able to uninstall it.

My latest try was to run the following from the mounted VS2015 ISO:
vs_community.exe /uninstall /force

It chugged along a bit and is now stuck on "*Applying: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Objects (x64)*"

Clicking "Analyze wait chain" on both vs_community.exe processes shows "running normally". It's been stuck for easily an hour now...

Is there a robust and bulletproof way of uninstalling VS 2015 in a clean way?

**Update**

I killed the process and tried again, it's now stuck on "*Applying: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK*"

**Update**

Clicking on Cancel makes it get stuck in "*Stopping current session...*"

Logs: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlUWmIwBtrrXhL502-esYJdASN1P5w

**Update**

After spending countless hours on trying various workarounds, ended up reinstalling Windows. Now all works!

Comment: It looks like the failed uninstall is due to the failed installation. You can try to use a healthy ISO file to repair it, temporary disable any anti-virus or anti-malware software before repair.  If this issue persists, you can use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder, then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: 1. Turned off Windows Defender
2. Disabled the lan network adapter
3. Mounted the ISO
4. Started vs_community.exe

Result: installer gets stuck at "Applying: Microsoft.NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack"

I've attached the logs to the question

Comment: I found the error code 0x8007064c, it means the installation location is not exist or you cannot access it, make sure you run the VS installer as administrator and you need to confirm the integrity of your ISO file. You can use the FCIV.exe tool: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2011/03/25/verify-the-iso-checksum-for-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-before-installing.aspx to check the SHA1 value of the ISO, the expected value of VS community 2015 with update 3(English) is 'C838DF0D2DAD6E763DF5A7974F5FFCD45B98FD0E', any discrepancy means the ISO is corrupted.

Comment: Meanwhile, please confirm the windows update is up-to-date before the installation.

Comment: Thank you. The SHA1 hash matches, so the ISO is solid. I haven't tried running the installer as admin, will do it now. Windows Update is mostly happy, but Security Update for Microsoft Silverlight (KB3182373) failed with Error 0x80070643

Comment: About the error 0x80070643 in Windows update, you can try to use the .NET Framework repair tool: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135 to repair the existing .NET Framework versions on your computer, and run the Fixit tool from: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall?wa=wsignin1.0, then re-run the installer as administrator.

Comment: Thanks Sara. I tried the repair tool (the Fixit link appears broken) and tried re-running the install. I was still getting errors about Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack with the installer asking me for files from "F:\ProgramData\Package Cache" that didn't exist.

Comment: As a last-ditch effort I tried deleting some of the registry values that pointed to non-existent paths, but it failed to solve the problem. Given the amount of time I've spent on this I am going to throw in the towel. This machine is a bit of a mess now since it was upgraded from Windows 7 - I will get around doing a clean install of Windows 10 and try again later.

Comment: have you successfully install VS on your clean windows 10? If not, you can share your latest VS installation logs.

Comment: Yes, after reinstalling Windows 10, VS 2015 installed without any further problems. Thanks for your help!